# Calling a repository from string in the Java Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-data

Is there a way to invoke an interface from a string?

```
String repName = "package." + modelName + "Repository";

Class<?> repo = Class.forName(repName);
Object obj = repo.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

Method setNameMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("findById", int.class);
setNameMethod.invoke(obj, 7); // passing 7
```

This should work for normal methods/classes, but how can I call an interface dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're acting inside the spring context you can use the `ApplicationContext`-bean:

```
@Component
class Test {
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public Test(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void callRepository(String repName) /* here should come some throws declarations */ {
        Class<?> type = Class.forName(repName);
        Object instance = context.getBean(repName);

        type.getMethod("findById", int.class).invoke(instance, 7);
    }
}
```

The `ApplicationContext` allows you to access every registered bean.